# How to get column names with query data in sqlite3?

Tags: android, sqlite, console-application

I use sqlite3 console to debug my app while it is executing in Android. Is there a way to show also column names (not only data) with data in result of sql query?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes, after logged into **sql** *prompt mode*, execute the following each at a time:

```
.header on
.mode column
```

Comment: further, if you run `.help` it will give you all the options available to run on sql-prompt

Comment: If your query results are too wide to fit on one line, then setting `.mode line` can be useful: it prints the fields one per line, in the format `<field name> = <field value>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
.headers on
.mode table
SELECT * FROM patients;
+--------------+-----------------+
| patient_name | patient_profile |
+--------------+-----------------+
| Name1        | 11              |
| Name2        | 11              |
| Name3        | 11              |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).